# Use && ("and") as if in ruby?

Tags: ruby

From some personal experimentation I've seen what seems to be a behavior of ruby "and"/"&&" that seems similar to an if statement.

```
  condition && action
```

seems to be doing the same as

```
  if condition
    action
  end
```

Are these equivalent?

Comment: I think including an else-branch evaluating to `false` would make them identical. Otherwise your if-expression returns `nil`.

Comment: Almost equivalent; there a difference with [Precedence](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html). `&&` is more higher precedence operation.

Comment: @sagarpandya82: The else branch should return `condition`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they're not exactly equivalent.

If `condition` is `false` :

```
condition && action
```

will return `false` but

```
if condition
  action
end
```

will return `nil`.

It's a small and subtle difference, but small differences can lead to big bugs.

Answer (score 4):

It's because `&&` short-circuits.

Take `a && b`. If `a` evaluates to false, then the expression is false regardless of what `b` is, so to avoid wasting time `b` is not evaluated. `b` only needs to be evaluated if `a` evaluates to true.

There's a similar short-circuiting behavior for `||` ('or'). Can you work out what it is?

[edit]

As Holger Just just pointed out, [when I say a "true" value in Ruby, I mean any *truthy* value, and when I mention a "false" value in Ruby, I mean any *falsey* value](https://gist.github.com/jfarmer/2647362). That is, `true` and `false` are *not* the only truthy and falsey values in Ruby. In fact, every value in Ruby except `nil` or `false` is truthy, with only those two exceptions being falsey. Notice that the string `"false"` and the number `0` are not one of those two exceptions, so they are actually truthy.

We can now fully describe the behavior of `a && b`:

- If `a` evaluates to a falsey value, then `a && b` returns the value of `a`, with `b` left unevaluated.
- If `a` evaluates to a truthy value, then `a && b` returns the value of `b`, resulting in both `a` and `b` being evaluated.

Comment: It should ne noted that whenever you speak of "false" in your answer, its actually a falsey value (i.e. a literal `nil` or `false`) and when speaking of "true", its any truethy value (i.e. anything other than `nil` or `false`).

Comment: I've been bitten by truthiness more than once: `"false"` (as a String) is also truthy.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I've incorporated some of your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Both **and** and **&&** are short-circuit evaluation, but **&&** takes higher-precedence and **and** takes lower-precedence. Below are couple examples,

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = a and b
# => 2
c
# => 1
c = a && b
# => 2
c
# => 2
```

So, we should be using **and** at some specific places.

Comment: Please include a pound sign (`#`) before `=>`  (`#=>` or `# =>`), so readers can cut and paste to run your code without additional editing. This is a general comment, not specific to this question. You may wish to point out that `c = a and b` is equivalent to `(c = a) and b` and `c = a && b` is the same as `c = (a && b)`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I just have updated the answer, thanks.

Comment: The question wasn't about `&&` and `and`, but about `if` and `&&`.

Comment: Also, `and` should never be used in Ruby. It caused too many headaches.